# Is 'He got a shot' the same as 'He got a bullet'?

Tags: meaning

Is it possible for the first expression to convey the meaning of the second in English, like 'He got a bullet in his body '?

Comment: In slang or informal English, *got a shot* means *has a chance*. For instance, "*Will he win?*" "*He got a shot.*" (*He [has] got a chance.*)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe possible in context, but very unlikely. That's simply not what *get a shot* means.

You can talk about "a shot" in terms of the shooter, but not when talking about the victim. "He got shot" (passive verb, not a noun).

You also wouldn't say "He got a bullet", unless you went on to say "in the arm" or "in the leg" etc.

[Barely relevant anecdote: the first time I encountered the phrase "a shot in the arm", I completely misunderstood it, because I was not familiar with "shot" = "injection" (that was a mainly American expression then).]

Comment: Thank you! I know that ' he got shot ' means ' he was shot ' (passive). I consider the passive to mean ' he was murdered ', please correct me if I'm wrong. In my doing this construction, I try to understand whether by adding 'a', and in this way change 'shot' to a noun, I am actually changing the meaning in such a way that it now means ' although he got a bullet in his body, he is alive'.

Comment: @zigzag. No. "He got certainly does **not** mean "he was murdered" or "he was killed". It often does imply this, but not necessarily. I know of no way just by playing around with the grammar to say "he was shot but not fatally".

Comment: OK, this explains a lot. I took it for granted, the meaning of the first phrase. Thank you!

Comment: I took it for granted that 'he got shot' means 'he was murdered' which has led me to confusion. However as the most explanations I get when searching, are that it is all about context, this made me curious about the possible existence of such a phrase.

Comment: I think it's possible to say "he got a bullet" without following it up with "in the arm" or whatever if it's used as a euphemism for "he was murdered". Example: "Sam the Snitch agreed to help police take down his boss. He got a bullet for his efforts."

Comment: @cjl750: that may be an idiom in some places, and I agree that in that context it would be read that way.

Comment: I found your answers very useful.

Comment: I'll note that in my experience, "a shot in the arm" is more likely used idiomatically than to refer to a literal injection.  In the context of injections, the location of the injection tends to be left unspecified (e.g., "I went to the doctor and got a flu shot.").

Comment: @Brian: I agree. But because I was not familiar with the literal meaning, I read "a shot in the arm" to mean "severe damage".